# Multiple versions of Python 2.7 on Windows 10

Tags: windows, python-2.7

I found many questions here about installing multiple versions of Python on the same machine, but I could not find a solution to my issue. I have Python 2.7.9 already installed (in c:\python27) and I want to perform some tests with Python 2.7.6, so I have also installed this version (in c:\python276). I run `c:\Python276\python.exe --version` but I am still getting `Python 2.7.9`

[image: The result of <code>pythhon --version</code> command]

Comment: Aside from the ssl changes, 2.7.6 and 2.7.9 are almost identical; I'm curious as to what you're testing?

Comment: @cco Just testing a 3rd-party library. I found on GitHub that it was tested only with Python 2.7.9 and I want to make sure that it works also with 2.7.6.

Answer (score 1):

It's more likely that 
`c:\windows\system32\python27.dll` is the Python 2.7.9 version, and that's what is getting loaded by `Python.exe` (any 2.7.x version).  I've never tried to have multiple 2.7.x versions at the same time, but since I can't find any copies of `python27.dll` in under `c:\Python27\`, my best suggestion is to completely uninstall all Python versions, then install them in ascending version order (i.e., `2.7.6`, then `2.7.9`), saving copies of `c:\windows\system32\python27.dll` at each step.  To run a particular minor version, make sure the appropriate `python27.dll` is the first one found on your path; you may want to capture all of `c:\python27\` as well, just to be sure you have consistent versions.